# Grep to find words that contain two z’s with two a’s

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find words that contain two z’s with two a’s between them (not necessarily consecutive) e.g. zeabraze . So far i got this but it only capture if zz or aa.

```
\bz{2}|a{2}\b
```

NOTE: I want to find the words that contain exactly two `z`s AND two `a`s.

Comment: Try `grep -o '\b\w*z\w*a\w*a\w*z\w*\b'`

Comment: can you apply any other tool (except grep)? What is your operation system?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that captures the words even if there more than two z's or two a's. And also i want to find the words that contain exacly two z's AND two a's

Comment: You did not mention that in the question. Try `grep -oiE '\b[b-y]*z([b-y]*a){2}[b-y]*z[b-y]*\b'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew solution can be improved by changing the `\w` with `[^az]`, i.e. a character class allowing anything but `a` and `z`.

Comment: yes, sorry . This is great . but in this also two a's has to be between the two z's . As an example "zaebrzae" this wouldn't be recognized. And i would be grateful if you can give a little explanation on your regular expression. Thank you

Comment: @imanshu15: So, did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your word contains only standard alphanumericals (a-z and 0-9) `z[B-Yb-y]*a[B-Yb-y]*a[B-Yb-y]*z` if there are more characters possible add them between the `[]`.

This regex means:

- `z` - Find sequence that starts with letter `z`,
- `[B-Yb-y]*` then it can be followed by any number of letters in between `b` and `y` (meaning all letters but `a` and `z`).
- `a` then we ensure that there is at least one `a`. If it can also be a capital letter "A", change to `[aA]`
- `[B-Yb-y]*a` our first `a` can be followed by any combination of letters that do not contain `a` or `z` themselves, and then another `a`
- `[B-Yb-y]*` and once again, any combination of letters between last `a` and `z`
- `z` and eventually, our string has to end with a `z`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
grep -oiE '\b[b-y]*z([b-y]*a){2}[b-y]*z[b-y]*\b'
```

The `o` option will extract matches, `i` will make the pattern case insensitive and `E` will allow the ERE syntax (no need to escape `()` and `{}` to make them special regex operators).

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `[b-y]*` - 0+ letters from the defined range (no `a`, no `z`, all others are matched)
- `z` - a `z`
- `([b-y]*a){2}` - 2 occurrences of

  - `[b-y]*` - 0+ ASCII letters  other than `a` and `z`
  - `a` - an `a`
- `[b-y]*` - 0+ ASCII letters  other than `a` and `z`
- `z` - a `z`
- `[b-y]*` - 0+ ASCII letters  other than `a` and `z`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

See the [grep demo](https://ideone.com/A3NC9S):

```
echo 'zeaz zeabraze zeazaz' | grep -oiE '\b[b-y]*z([b-y]*a){2}[b-y]*z[b-y]*\b'
```

only returns `zeabraze`.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** approach:

```
echo "zeabraze axaxzxzxz acaxzcz" | awk -v RS=" " '/^[^z]*z[^z]*z[^z]*$/ && /^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*$/'
```

The output:

```
zeabraze
acaxzcz
```